# count values in a php array and eliminate repeated

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to count the values in a php array and eliminate repetitions have leaving only 1. The format of my arrangement is as follows:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [inscripcion_id] => 3932
        [nombre] => Prueba
        [email] => prueba@prueba.cl
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [inscripcion_id] => 3926
        [nombre] => Prueba
        [email] => prueba@prueba.cl
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [inscripcion_id] => 3921
        [nombre] => Nicolas
        [email] => nico@prueba.com
    )
)
```

I look matches are based on the `email` field, if the email appears more than 1 time in the arrangements must be eliminated leaving only 1. The problem is I can not get as often appears no less eliminate it. Try `array_count_values` does not work, I can find the matches of each email but only in the subarray therefore always find 1 each as follows for example:

```
Array ( [3932] => 1 [Prueba] => 1 [prueba@prueba.cl] => 1 ) 
Array ( [3926] => 1 [Prueba] => 1 [prueba@prueba.cl] => 1 )
```

I hope the result is this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [inscripcion_id] => 3932
        [nombre] => Prueba
        [email] => prueba@prueba.cl
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [inscripcion_id] => 3921
        [nombre] => Nicolas
        [email] => nico@prueba.com
    )
)
```

Comment: take a look at this http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Could you show what the expected result will be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Should do it.

```
print_r(unique_multidim_array($array, 'email'));

function unique_multidim_array($array, $key){
    $temp_array = array();
    $i = 0;
    $key_array = array();

    foreach($array as $val){
        if(!in_array($val[$key],$key_array)){
            $key_array[$i] = $val[$key];
            $temp_array[$i] = $val;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $temp_array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with the email fields and remove from source array if duplicate:

```
$temp  = array();
$out   = array();
foreach( $array as $k => $v ) {
    if ( isset( $temp[$v['email']] ) )
        unset( $array[$k]);
    else {
        $temp[$v['email']] = $k;
        array_push( $out, $v );
    }
}
```

The original array is in `$array` and the output in `$out`

If the key is not important an easier way is

```
$temp  = array();
foreach( $array as $k => $v ) {
    if ( isset( $temp[$v['email']] ) )
        unset( $array[$k]);
    else
        $temp[$v['email']] = $k;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to make an array index by the `email` (like a primary key).

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'inscripcion_id'=>3932,
        'nombre'=>'Prueba',
        'email'=>'prueba@prueba.cl'
    ),
    array(
        'inscripcion_id'=>3926,
        'nombre'=>'Prueba',
        'email'=>'prueba@prueba.cl'
    ),
    array(
        'inscripcion_id'=>3921,
        'nombre'=>'Nicolas',
        'email'=>'nico@prueba.com'
    ),
);

$result = array();

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array($value['email'], $result)) {
        $result[$value['email']] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Result:

```
array (size=2)
  'prueba@prueba.cl' => 
    array (size=3)
      'inscripcion_id' => int 3926
      'nombre' => string 'Prueba' (length=6)
      'email' => string 'prueba@prueba.cl' (length=16)
  'nico@prueba.com' => 
    array (size=3)
      'inscripcion_id' => int 3921
      'nombre' => string 'Nicolas' (length=7)
      'email' => string 'nico@prueba.com' (length=15)
```

Also you can have direct access to every sub array you want using it's email value:

```
var_dump($result['prueba@prueba.cl']);
```

Result:

```
array (size=3)
  'inscripcion_id' => int 3926
  'nombre' => string 'Prueba' (length=6)
  'email' => string 'prueba@prueba.cl' (length=16)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create the result array with the email as the key, then there are no duplicates:

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    $result[$value['email']] = $value;
}
```

Then if you want to reset the keys:

```
$result = array_values($result);
```